# How best to display a catalog in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to implement the output of the product catalog.
The template is simple, the image and the name are at the bottom.
The images will go in a row and move down depending on the screen.
Previously, I created an Itemscontrol, the itemssource of which took data from the database.

I know that the option works with its own difficulties, but is it optimal or is there another way?

```
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="200">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="250"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You should know that WrapPanel has a bad performance impact. This will be relevant if you expect to display many items. Better use the classic vertical stacking by using a ListBox instead. ListBox extends ItemsControl to add special performance features that are enabled by default as well as a ScrollViewer.